# How to Know If I am in a Terminal Service (TS) Session?

Tags: winapi, terminal-services

Is there any windows API function to check if I am in a terminal service session?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
GetSystemMetrics(SM_REMOTECONTROL))
```

To determine if the calling session is being remotely controlled

and

```
GetSystemMetrics(SM_REMOTESESSION))
```

to determine if the calling session is associated with a remote session on a terminal server

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724385%28VS.85%29.aspx